# Date subtraction from two date column Django ORM for filter

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, django-orm

I have two keys/columns in MongoDB. I am using Django ORM to get data from mongo using a connector called djongo.
I need a apply a filter. I have to take a difference from the column date and check if the difference is less than 24 hours.

This is my query -

```
time_threshold = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

total_count = ArticleFeed.objects.annotate(
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(F('crawled') - F('published'), output_field=DurationField())
).filter(diff__lte=time_threshold,
         crawled__lte=report_start_ISO, crawled__gte=last_ISO, data_source="TOI").exclude(
    reject='repeat').count()
```

But I am getting the following exception -

> File
>   "/home/embed/inmobi/content_curation_project/ccp_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py",
>   line 621, in subtract_temporals
>       raise NotSupportedError("This backend does not support %s subtraction." % internal_type) django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: **This
>   backend does not support DateTimeField subtraction.**

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as the error indicates you are trying to make unsupported operation.  I am not conversant with Django but I would suggest casting your fields as date and then perform your operation. E. G date(F('crawled')) - date(F('published'))